# How to correctly trim a string when reading/writing a file.txt in fortran90?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, character, trim

I'm a beginner with fortran90, I want to read a txt file that in my case is: "Simulation_Parameters.txt". This is my code:

```
!declarations
  integer, intent(in) :: iu_input
  character*150, intent(in)  :: input_path,input_filename

!read file
open(iu_input,file = trim(input_path)//trim(input_filename),status='old',action='read')
```

P.s. I've added the visualization of the variable   `input_path` and I suspect that the problem is the blank space bewteen text and the superscript. I've a similar problem with the variable  `input_filename`

Compiler: Intel fortran compiler.

Error message:

```
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\peppe\OneDrive - Università di Napoli Federico II\MSc_Aerospace_Eng_thesis_personal_work\Fortran_projects\LibrationPoints\LibrationPoints\LibrationPoints\x64\Debug\LibrationPoints.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2022.0.0\windows\redist\intel64_win\compiler\libmmdd.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2022.0.0\windows\redist\intel64_win\compiler\libifcoremdd.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imagehlp.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2022.0.0\windows\redist\intel64_win\compiler\libmmd.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dbghelp.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
LibrationPoints.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

Input file (Simulation_Parameters.txt):

```
&nm_files
    iu_out1 = 10,
    iu_out2 = 11,
    output_path = 'C:\Users\peppe\OneDrive - Università di Napoli Federico II\MSc_Aerospace_Eng_thesis_personal_work\Fortran_projects\LibrationPoints\OutputFiles\',
    output_filename1 = 'Lagrange_Points_Positions.txt',
    output_filename2 = 'Lagrange_Points_Acc_Residuals.txt'
/  
&nm_CR3BP   !  (source:https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/solar-system/our-solar-system/overview/)
    m1 = 5.97217e24,     ! Earth [kg]
        ! m1 = 1.9891e30,    ! Sun [kg] 
        ! m1 = 5.68319e26,   ! Saturn [kg]    
        m2 = 7.34767e22,      ! Moon [kg] 
        ! m2 = 1.079446e20,   ! Enceladus [kg]
        unit_distance = 384400.0  ! Earth-Moon system distance (km) take value from SS dynamics
/
&nm_Lagrange
    Lagrange_tol = 1.e-6
/
```

Previous problem solved! I missed '\'at the end of the input file path.

Now I have a similar problem when writing on new files by using the data imported by the previus .txt file.
Here the code:

```
 open(unit = iu_out1, file = trim(output_path) // trim(output_filename1), status = 'unknown', action = 'write')
    open(unit = iu_out2, file = trim(output_path) // trim(output_filename2), status = 'unknown', action = 'write')
```

The error output is the following one:

```
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\peppe\OneDrive - Università di Napoli Federico II\MSc_Aerospace_Eng_thesis_personal_work\Fortran_projects\LibrationPoints\LibrationPoints\LibrationPoints\x64\Debug\LibrationPoints.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2022.0.0\windows\redist\intel64_win\compiler\libmmdd.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2022.0.0\windows\redist\intel64_win\compiler\libifcoremdd.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imagehlp.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\2022.0.0\windows\redist\intel64_win\compiler\libmmd.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dbghelp.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'LibrationPoints.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
LibrationPoints.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fotran questions. Please include all error messages **as text**. It is **very important** for the error messages to be searchable for people with similar problems. Also, I cannot read the small letters from your picture at all. It is just impossible. Copy and paste the error message as text. Which compiler do you use? The code you show in the short sample looks OK to me. Show us more code. See [mcve]. The code in the picture is useless, we need it in the question.

Comment: At a guess, you're not including the `/` between the `input_path` and `input_filename`?

Comment: That was also my guess even before getting the details. I think this can be closed as a simple typo. BTW I recommend using `/` instead of `\\`. They are perfectly acceptable even in MS Windows and more universal.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF and sorry for my inaccurate question! I've added additional info to my question.

Comment: I recommend `trim(input_path) // '/' // trim(input_filename)`. Any extra `/` does not harm, `//` is the same as just one `/`.

Comment: Reading file problem solved! Now I have a similar one when writing new files, I've updated the question. 
Hope you can help me.

Comment: You really need to find out where your compiler prints the actual error messages. The "LibrationPoints.exe has triggered a breakpoint." tells nothing. Try compiling from the command line to get something useful, because what you get from the Visual Studio is really useless unless you can learn how to use it for detailed debugging. Just use `ifort -g -check -warn filename.f90` Or really learn how to use the integrated debugger.

Comment: This feature seems to be new in the 2022 version of Visual Studio + Intel oneAPI. Perhaps they could guide you at the official Intel Fortran support forum. They key is to get the actual error message. What does the program output say? What did your program print?

Comment: The actual error message will be in the console window that pops up when you run the program.  There is no practical difference between running from within Visual Studio and running from the command line in this regard.

Comment: @IanH I suspected that be the case. The breakpoint message is quite confusing, is the program actually just paused in a debugger or has the execution actually ended?

Comment: The "has triggered a breakpoint" message (and previous lines) is from the debugger, as reported in the debugger output pane.  The program is paused at the point that the Fortran runtime raised an error.  The focus has returned to Visual Studio in anticipation of the user wanting to debug the error. Sometimes this happens quickly enough that users do not notice that a console window has been created separate to the Visual Studio window.  The Visual Studio window is likely "on top" of the relevant console window - the OP should look in the task bar for a "strange" window icon and click on it.

Comment: Problem solved: I am almost sure that the problem was the accented letter "à", so I preferred to avoid using it and so I changed the path name!
Thanks to everyone for your support.